# How to view long strings in file properties details

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I right-click a DLL, select Properties and click on then the Details tab. As you can see in the following screenshots, long strings are clipped (...) and there does not seem to be a way to resize the window or copy the value.

How can I get the full strings from this dialog?

[image]

Comment: See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/493009/138343) if you want to copy the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two ways**

1. While holding the `Ctrl-key` press on the `+` key if you have a numpad. This should resize the widths of the column so that they are all readable. ***OR***
2. Go to the vertical line as shown in the picture below and as you hover over it, you cursor should change to the `horizontal resize` cursor. Pull it to the right and a horizontal scroll bar should appear at the bottom allowing you to scroll horizontally to read the rest of the text.
   [image]

In either case, the horizontal scroll bar should appear at the bottom as shown here as an example:
[image]

Comment: Using method 2, you can also double-click on the vertical line to automatically resize it to fit.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that column resize line! And thanks for the double-click/Ctrl+Plus tricks, I did not know those.

Answer (score 1):

Use this DLL from Codeproject, which restores the old XP dialog:

**[Windows 7 File-properties "Version" Tab Shell Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118909/Windows-7-File-properties-Version-Tab-Shell-Extens)**

[image]

Here you can copy the data easily :)

> Unfortunately, it neither shows all of the same information as before nor does it 
>   support copying and pasting of any of the displayed information either.
>
> With the handy dandy VersInfoEx Shell Extension however, that's no
>   longer true! The VersInfoEx Shell Extension brings back the missing
>   Version tab functionality to Windows 7!

Comment: Oh that's fantastic, thanks for the link! Pity users have to undo MS' butchery of its own OS.

Comment: yeah, I've also missed this and was so happy to find this DLL.