# Select and copy any text?

Tags: windows, copy-paste

Many GUI elements (windows, dialogs...) have text that does not support selecting and copying to the clipboard. (Windows error dialogs are a special case: ctrl-c will copy all their text to clipboard, without explicitly selecting it first. It even includes the window title.)

Is there a way to copy those "non-selectable" texts?

---

This answer from another question seems to fit perfectly: https://superuser.com/a/493009/86828

Comment: I remember this problem was solved by an utility on AmigaOS that allowed to select and copy any text, as long it was rendered by the system text functions. (forgot the name, maybe _PowerCopy_...).

Comment: Do you have a specific control type you're asking about?  Some controls handle copy/paste on their own.

Comment: The problem with doing this in Windows is that MS changes the way these things are done every few years (leaving the old libraries around so as not to break anything written in the short lived API). This means that if someone were to write an app which did this they'd need to replace \ hook into at least a half dozen different system APIs. This isn't going to ever be realistically doable. If you know that the application is using the new(er) WPF forms then you can get the text you are looking for using the WPF forms inspector: http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why was the mention of Windows OS deleted? Any solution would be OS specific and a solution for QNX would be useless to me.

Comment: Have you looked at screen readers as a possible way of accessing the text?

Comment: Long time ago, there was an application named "Aqua Deskperience" that can extract text from screen element. But as I remember it seems to work with XP only, not Win7.

Comment: @DavidBalažic: _Why was the mention of Windows OS deleted?_ Probably because WIndows is already specified in the tags.

Comment: The Amiga tool I was talking about is [PowerSnap](http://aminet.net/package/util/cdity/PowerSnap22a).

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there any way a user can view or copy non-editable GUI controls' contents at runtime?](http://superuser.com/questions/492818), [Read the contents of a ComboBox (or any other windows control)](http://superuser.com/questions/130103), [How to capture text from the operating system in a practical and simple way?](http://superuser.com/questions/660750) ...

Comment: @Karan The last one seems like a duplicate, but has no useful answers. The first one is not a duplicate, but has a useful answer (HyperSnap and maybe SnagIt). Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBalažic: How is the first one not a duplicate? You're asking about copying non-selectable text from GUI elements, and that thread is about copying non-editable text from GUI controls. Without splitting hairs about selectable vs. editable, the meaning and aim are the same here. Second one's accepted answer is also valid and provided here as well by harrymc. All in all I guess you could have saved your rep easily by using some better search terms.

Comment: @Karan That question asks about copying content from invisible text, hidden as it says in first paragraph and drop-down in second (also not visible until clicked). I ask about regular plain text displayed on screen. Like all the text in the System info dialog (press WINDOWS+Pause keys) in Windows 7/8. Nirsoft SysExpoter from the second one's answer does not work at all for this case (neither the ones from harrymc's answer here). It does not even detect any Firefox window in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few utilities that can extract text from text-containing
controls found in dialogs and windows. Here are some such products :

[Nirsoft SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html)
[GetWindowText](http://www.softwareok.com/?Download=GetWindowText)
[WinScraper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5686/Screen-capture-window-resizing-utility-with-source)
[ShoWin](http://www.mcafee.com/uk/downloads/free-tools/showin.aspx)
[Spyxx](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.fr/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html)
[WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17)

I only have experience with Nirsoft SysExporter, which works.

For the cases where these utilities do not work,
one can use a screen-reading OCR.
I am quite happy for these cases with the multilingual [ABBYY Screenshot Reader](http://www.abbyy.com/screenshot_reader/).
This is commercial software selling for $29.99 or €9,95,
but I got it via a [free offer](http://dottech.org/25252/free-abbyy-screenshot-reader/) that might still be running,
or similar offers can be found via google.
OCR is not perfect, but usually gets correctly almost all of the text.